# How to get the list of the environment variable from the jenkins in the test case

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am creating a test case for a plugin, I want to fetch all the environment variables that are present on the current Jenkins server. Can anyone tell me how to fetch all the environment variables from the Jenkins server?

```
   public class VariableExistsConditionTest {

    @Rule public JenkinsRule j = new JenkinsRule(); 


     @Test
      public void someTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty prop = new EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
         EnvVars env = prop.getEnvVars();
         env.put("DEPLOY_TARGET", "staging");
         j.jenkins.getGlobalNodeProperties().add(prop);
        //Code to fetch the environment variables


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all environment variables use

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
```